# Getting error while using context menu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, contextmenu

I am new to mvc and i am using context menu plugin in it but it keep on throwing this exception :[image]

I have used these css in my _layout.cshtml

```
<!----Contwxt Menu Css-->
<link href="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have used these scripts in my _layout.cshtml:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have added jquery.contextmenu.min.js.map in my project but i don't know how to add it in my _layout.cshtml

Any help will be appreciated as i'm struck in this for long.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `_layout`, you need to add all scripts like the following code

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  }
```

Note: If you have minified version of scripts, it´s irrelevant to add normal one.

Aside note, you can add it to a bundle, so in your `bundle config` you can do:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscripts").Include(
                "~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.ui.position.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"));
```

Then you can call in your `_layout` like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscripts")
```

Any question of it, I can help you, regards!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when i use only minified scripts it is giving me error of /Scripts/Plugins/jquery.contextMenu.min.css.map was not found and when i use only minified css and javscript then no action takes place on right click.Please let me know what to do.

Comment: I´m not sure but check this line `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscripts").Include`, Verify is `ScriptBundle` and not `StyleBundle`, because you have `.css.map`

Answer (score 0):

Also please note, you have the scripts in double. Either add the .min version or the normal version.